# Why hibernate generates insert and update for OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to understand the one-to-many mapping in Hibernate with a small example. I have a `Product` with a set of `Part's`. Here are my entity classes:

`Part.java`

```
@Entity
public class Part {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    String partName;
    //Setters & Getters
}
```

`Product.java`

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    private String serialNumber;
    private Set<Part> parts = new HashSet<Part>();
    @Id
    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    public Set<Part> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }
    // Setter methods
}
```

Then I tried to save some parts and products in my database and observed below queries generated by hibernate:

```
Hibernate: insert into Product (serialNumber) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Part (partName, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update Part set PRODUCT_ID=? where id=?
```

Here to add a record in `Part` table, hibernate generates 2 DML operations - `insert` and `update`. If a single `insert` command is sufficient to add a record in table then why hibernate uses both insert and update in this case? Please explain.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is crazy old but I had the same problem and Google brought me here, so after fixing it I figured I should post an answer.

Hibernate will switch the insert/update approach to straight inserts if you make the join column not nullable and not updatable, which I assume in your case it is neither anyways:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
```

Comment: Does setting `updatable=false` mean that if `Product` and it's `Part`s are updated later by calling `saveOrUpdate`, then `Part`s will not be updated in the DB?

Comment: No. It simply means that column is not updatable once the entry is made. Updates on other columns, depending on their definition of course, will still occur as normal.

Comment: Just a heads up: while this indeed removed the extra `UPDATE` calls, since I am using EclipseLink's `batch-writing`, it has also split my `INSERT INTO` calls and thus resulted in worse performance.

Answer (score 0):

If Part as composite element list then only two query will come. Please check and revert.

If its not a composite element , hibernate try to insert individual as a separate query and it will try to create relationship between them.

In earlier case hibernate will insert with relationship key.

Answer (score -1):

****Hibernate: insert into Product (serialNumber) values (?)**

**Hibernate: insert into Part (partName, id) values (?, ?)****

In these two queries hibernate is simply inserting a record into the database.
At that stage hibernate is not creating any relationship between the two entities.

**Hibernate: update Part set PRODUCT_ID=? where id=?**

Now after making entity tables,hibernate is going to make a relationship between the two
by using the above third query...

Answer (score -1):

The association is uni-directional, so `Product` is the owning side (because it's the only side).

Make the association bidirectional and make `Part` the association owner. That way you will avoid redundant updates because the foreign key values will be specified as part of insert statements for `Part`.