# How to avoid insert and update queries in one-to-many uni-directional association

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I have a simple `one-to-many` relationship between `Employee` & `Phone` entities.

I have 2 issues here.

**Scenario 1 :**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>(0);

// Setters & Getter methods

}
```

**Phone.java**

```
@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String type;
    private int areaCode;
    private String phoneNumber;

// Setter & Getters

}
```

Now I created employee instance and added 2 phones to it.

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(10,"Bob", "Way",50000);
Phone p1 = new Phone(1,"home",613,"792-0000");
Phone p2 = new Phone(2,"work",613,"896-1234");          
e1.addPhone(p1);
e1.addPhone(p2);
```

Then in hibernate, if I use below code:

```
session.save(e1);
session.save(p1);
session.save(p2);
```

or if I save `phone` then `employee`

```
session.save(p1);
session.save(p2);
session.save(e1);
```

In both cases, Hibernate just runs `insert` queries with out any `update` queries but the `foreign key` is set to NULL.

```
mysql> select * from Phone;
+----+----------+-------------+------+-----------+
| id | areaCode | phoneNumber | type | parent_id |
+----+----------+-------------+------+-----------+
|  1 |      613 | 792-0000    | home |      NULL |
|  2 |      613 | 896-1234    | work |      NULL |
|  3 |      416 | 123-4444    | work |      NULL |
+----+----------+-------------+------+-----------+
```

How can I fix this? Please let me know where I made mistake.

**Scenario 2 :**

Now if I made change to my `@JoinColumn` in `Employee` table like below:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
```

Then Hibernate is generating `**insert**` then `update` queries to map the foreign key properly.

```
Hibernate: insert into Employee (firstName, lastName, salary) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Phone (areaCode, phoneNumber, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Phone (areaCode, phoneNumber, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Phone (areaCode, phoneNumber, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Phone set parent_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update Phone set parent_id=? where id=?
```

When Hibernate runs the `insert` on `Employee` table then it gets the `employee id` there itself, then why does Hibernate runs additional `update` query when it can just run a single insert query on Phone table by including the foreign key value?

I understand that in `update` query it is adding the foreign key, but I would like to know why this is not managed in `insert` query itself on Phone table. Can you please explain this?

**Scenario 3:**

If I say like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
```

Then I get below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : onetomany.Phone._phones_OWNER_IDBackref
```

Comment: Please refer links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223952/how-to-avoid-hibernate-generating-two-queries-for-an-update-with-onetomany?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591684/hibernate-many-to-one-updating-foreign-key-to-null

Comment: For scenarios 1) and 3), you specified `insertable=false, updatable=false`, so it is obvious why the values are not saved. For scenario 2), as already pointed by @NitinPrabhu, duplicate of those questions.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, can you please tell when we need to use `insertable=false, updatable=false` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a Employee and an Phone.

You'd like to add insertable=false, updatable=false to the @OneToMany relationship with the Employee entity in the Phone entity, simply because it's not the responsibility of the Phone entity to create or update a Employee. It's the other way round.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double salary;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>(0);

    // Setters & Getter methods

}

@Entity
public class Phone {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String type;
    private int areaCode;
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PHONE_FK")
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Employee employee;

}
```

Comment: `@JoinColumn` and `@Column` cannot be used together in JPA. You will get a Runtime exception. For more, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121485/columns-not-allowed-on-a-manytoone-property