# JPA saveAll forces UPDATE call after INSERT INTO on OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

## Context

Our `PUT` endpoint essentially does an `UPSERT` by first calling `DELETE` on all the entities, and then calls `INSERT INTO`.

However, when debugging, I see that there are some `UPDATE` calls being issued by JPA too, and I'm trying to avoid that for performance reasons. I want there to be only 2 `INSERT` calls: one for the `Parent`, and one for all the `Child`.

This seems to only happen for the `@OneToMany` entities.

If it can help, we use EclipseLink as our JPA provider, and `batch-writing` is activated. The application is built with Spring Data.

## Model

```java
@Entity
@Table
@Data // org.lombok
@IdClass(ParentPrimaryKey.class)
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product", updatable = false)
    private String product;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "source", updatable = false)
    private String source;

    @Column
    private String whatever;


    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "product"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "source", referencedColumnName = "source")
    })
    private List<Child> details;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
@Data // org.lombok
@IdClass(ChildPrimaryKey.class)
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product", updatable = false)
    private String product;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "source", updatable = false)
    private String source;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "extra", updatable = false)
    private String extra;

    @Column
    private String foo;

    @Column
    private String bar;
}
```

##### Associated current logs

```
INSERT INTO PARENT (product, source, whatever) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [A, A, A]
    bind => [B, B, A]

INSERT INTO CHILD (product, source, extra, foo, bar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [A, A, 1, B, B]
    bind => [A, A, 2, C, C]
    bind => [A, A, 3, D, D]
    bind => [B, B, 1, B, B]
    bind => [B, B, 2, C, C]
    bind => [B, B, 3, D, D]

UPDATE CHILD SET product = ?, source = ? WHERE ((product = ?) AND (source = ?) AND (extra = ?))
    bind => [A, A, A, A, 1]
    bind => [A, A, A, A, 2]
    bind => [A, A, A, A, 3]
    bind => [B, B, B, B, 1]
    bind => [B, B, B, B, 2]
    bind => [B, B, B, B, 3]
```

## Attempted fix

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457083/9768291), I tried adding `nullable=false` :

```java
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String product;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "source", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String source;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "extra", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String extra;

    // the rest is identical...
}
```

##### Resulting logs

As can be seen, this indeed removes the `UPDATE` call, but it increases the amount of total queries that will be issued to our DB, and thus means the performance will actually be worse (it will go from a total of 3 requests, to 2N):

```
INSERT INTO PARENT (product, source, whatever) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [A, A, A]
INSERT INTO CHILD (product, source, extra, foo, bar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [A, A, 1, B, B]
    bind => [A, A, 2, C, C]
    bind => [A, A, 3, D, D]


INSERT INTO PARENT (product, source, whatever) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [B, B, A]
INSERT INTO CHILD (product, source, extra, foo, bar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [B, B, 1, B, B]
    bind => [B, B, 2, C, C]
    bind => [B, B, 3, D, D]
```

Comment: You have a unidirectional mapping from Parent->Child, and have mapped it so that parent owns/controls the foreign key values that exist within the child table. Unfortunately for you, that means that EclipseLink must insert the child row in one statement (tied to the Child entity) and update it later when dealing with the Parent entity separately. If you want it done in one statement, you need to tie the columns to the Child entity completely. Easiest way is to make the OneToMany a bidirectional mapping, so that Child knows its parent - there are plenty of examples of how to do it

Comment: Alternatively - I think you might have gotten your mappings wrong, as you have duplicate mappings controlling the Child.source and Child.product columns - Parent writes to them through the parent.details mapping, and child does through the source/product basic id mappings. This shouldn't be allowed. Your issue goes away if you mark the OneToMany as insertable/updateable=false. Just add that to the join column definitions, making that mapping read only. You must already be setting the basic columns in each child entity directly anyway, so there is no point to that

Comment: The reason for the behaviour change, to batch writing performance, is again due to the oneToMany being unidirectional. EclipseLink must processes all objects it manages, and makes a rough ordering based on the relationships, so that it can look up and set all the foreign keys appropriately. This is why you saw the inserts then updates for the child records being separate. When you made the field not-nullable, EclipseLink detected it and has special handling to combing the fk handling into the child insert - but it was added as a bug fix, not a full feature that has batch writing support;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that may work better for you.

## First option

Keeping everything else unchanged:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data // org.lombok
@IdClass(ParentPrimaryKey.class)
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product", updatable = false)
    private String product;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "source", updatable = false)
    private String source;

    @Column
    private String whatever;


    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "product", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "source", referencedColumnName = "source", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private List<Child> details;
}
```

This will ensure that the foreign keys in the Child table are controlled only by their respective @Id mappings.

## Second option

Alternatively, you can go the other way around and have JPA set the values in the child entity instance entirely for you with what is known as a derived ID:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ChildPrimaryKey.class)
public class Child {
    @Id
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "product", referencedColumnName = "product"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "source", referencedColumnName = "source")
    })
    Parent parent;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "extra")
    private String extra;

    // the rest is identical...
}

public class ChildPrimaryKey {
    ParentPrimaryKey parent;
    String extra;
}
```

This will ensure the source and product columns are set in the Child table based on the Parent instance's values. The Parent's details mapping then can remove the join columns definition and just state it is mapped by the Child's parent relationship:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Child> details;
```

Comment: Amazing! The first option worked like a charm.

Comment: Followup question: is there a way to execute this in a single `INSERT` statement, rather than 2 ? (With JPQL, Native, or maybe even Stored Procedure?)