# why @OneToMany Unidirectional association with @JoinColumn in JPA with springboot generates extra queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project and I have felt like in @OneToMany Unidirectional association  with @JoinColumn in JPA with springboot generates extra queries. For example if we have 2 entities

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
 
    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
 
@Entity(name = "PostComment")
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String review;
 
    //Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity
}
```

when we run the following code

```
Post post = new Post("First post");
 
post.addComment(
    new PostComment("My first review")
);
post.addComment(
    new PostComment("My second review")
);
post.addComment(
    new PostComment("My third review")
);
 
entityManager.persist(post);
```

it generates following queries

```
insert into post (title, id)
values ('First post', 1)
 
insert into post_comment (review, id)
values ('My first review', 2)
 
insert into post_comment (review, id)
values ('My second review', 3)
 
insert into post_comment (review, id)
values ('My third review', 4)
 
update post_comment set post_id = 1 where id = 2
 
update post_comment set post_id = 1 where id =  3
 
update post_comment set post_id = 1 where id =  4
```

Now my question is that why does JPA updates post_comment records after inserting post_comment records ? why didn't JPA insert the post_comment records with the post_id while it was inserting records in post_comment table so that it don't have to update records again ?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379046/why-hibernate-generates-insert-and-update-for-onetomany-mapping

Comment: You are using unidirectional association, PostComment doesn't know to which Post it belongs, for that reason you have that generated update statements. If you use a biderectional association, you will avoid those additional update statements, the best practice is to use bidirectional association for OneToMany.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why hibernate generates insert and update for OneToMany mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379046/why-hibernate-generates-insert-and-update-for-onetomany-mapping)

Comment: @xmen-5 the JPA first persists the post, so it has the post_id before persisting the post-comment, So then how does not it now that this post_comment belongs to which post ?

Comment: @K.Nicholas this answers gives the solution but doesn't explain that why JPA has this behaviour. I don't want solution, i want to understand the problem that why does JPA behaves like this

Comment: @a_a this answers gives the solution but doesn't explain that why JPA has this behaviour. I don't want solution, i want to understand the problem that why does JPA behaves like this

Comment: This user has never accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are depending on the `CascadeType.ALL` to insert the `PostComments` for you. Why is that? I consider that a JPA anti-pattern. JPA specifies that the `owner` of the relationship will persist relations. See [If the relationship is bidirectional, the mappedBy element must be used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) You have not specified an `owner` of the relationship.

What in the JPA specification can you point to that dictates that using the `CascadeType` should be implemented in any specific fashion?

What you show kind of makes sense to me. The `Post` is saved, the `PostComments` are saved b/c of the `CascadeType`, and then the `Post` id updated into the `PostComments`. You didn't set the `Post` id into the `PostComments` yourself so you don't have any say about how the implementation does it. I have seen `CascaseType` do some interesting things, but it's still an anti-pattern as far as I'm concerned. **If you don't understand it, don't use it!**

Besides that, you have also added a static `= new ArrayList<>()` on comments. Another anti-pattern. The majority of those `new ArrayLists` will be tossed onto the garbage heap in very short order. Even though Java manages memory for you, you should have some idea of how you are using it.

Short answer, the `PostComments` should be saved by you specifically, but only when you already have saved the `Post` and it is ready to be set into the `PostComment`. Of course, you should have the `Post` and the `ManyToOne` in the `PostComment` so you can do that.

I don't know if you've investigated the `Query` behaviors of the related `Entities`, but I think you'll find more surprises there as well. Since I have already done that, I make these comments.

References:

[What is the "owning side" in an ORM mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749689/what-is-the-owning-side-in-an-orm-mapping)

[37.1 Entities](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA)